# AlertDialog not showing at .show() - Xamarin Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, android-alertdialog

I have the following code:

```
private void CloseOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder alert = new Android.Support.V7.App.AlertDialog.Builder(this);

    alert.SetTitle("Cerrar Pedido");
    alert.SetMessage("Are you sure?");
    alert.SetCancelable(true);
    alert.SetPositiveButton("Confirm", delegate { this.Rta = true; });
    alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { this.Rta = false; });
    Dialog dialog = alert.Create();
    dialog.Show();

    if (this.Rta)
    {
        //Some code here
    }

}
```

this.Rta is a property of my class.

The problem is that the alert doesn't show at `dialog.show()`, it shows once the method `CloseOrder()` ended, so `this.Rta` never gets the corresponding value assigned.

I've been searching a lot but I can't find a solution, if anyone can help me that'd be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dialog.Show()` is asynchronous method, that means `CloseOrder(object sender, EventArgs e)` and `dialog.Show()` end up at the same time.

You can not get the 'Rta' assigned value at the `CloseOrder` function.

You will get the value when you click the **confirm** or **cancel** button of the dialog.

I suggest you to use message sender in the `delegate{this.Rta = true}`

For example:

```
mHandler handler = new mHandler();
Message message = new Message();
message.What = 1;
alert.SetPositiveButton("Confirm", delegate { this.Rta = true; handler.SendMessage(message); });
alert.SetNegativeButton("Cancel", delegate { this.Rta = false; handler.SendMessage(message); });
```

//....

```
class mHandler : Handler{
        public override void HandleMessage(Message message) {
            switch (message.What) {
                case 1:
                     if (this.Rta)
                     {
                          //Some code here
                     }
                     break;
                }
            }
        }
```